# USB Movie Media Center

Tags: usb, kodi, software-development, hard-drive, media

**Problem**

I got a smart tv which already contains a good media center, but this media center is too overcrowded, means it has too much feautures and it's confused.

*XBMC is better than the media center of my tv but it's also overcrowded for my needs...*

My only needs are to show a list with all my movies (just the movies) on my usb harddrive and then I should be able to select and watch one of them.

**Question**

Is there a solution for my problem yet? Can I configure xbmc to disable all the menus (photos, music...) except the movies and/or start directly in the movies menu? Or do I have to write a solution for this myself? And if so, where should I start?

Comment: Are you asking this in context of using a Raspberry Pi for XBMC? Otherwise, this question is a bit off-topic here, as this site is Raspberry Pi-specific.

Comment: you may disable all menus (Photos, Music, Weather) easily. you should start from the Settings menu -- it's all there.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness I've got a Raspberry Pi and I want to use it as my new media center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most XBMC skins allow you to disable the menu items you don't want. It's usually in the Skin settings.

Settings → Appearance → Skin → Skin Settings.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13v0j.jpg) of a very clean-looking home screen.

<sub>(The skin is Amber, which can be installed easily: Settings → Appearance → Skin  → (Choose Skin) → Get More...)</sub>

Comment: Amazing, I'll try it, thank you. How about start directly in the movies menu, is this possible too? I want that my Raspberry Pi opens automatically the movies menu after boot, is this possible too with XBMC?

Comment: Settings → Appearance → Skin → Startup Window. Strangely, while there's a "TV" option, there's no "Movies" option, at least not for me. The closest I can see is "Videos".

Comment: Apparently you _can_ set you home window to Movies, but it requires some light scripting: [How to set Startup Window to MOVIES](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=166699).